# Correctly bind data to dynamic Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

My view model consists of 6 fields:

```
public int Program { get; set; NotifyPropChange("Program"); }
public int Customer { get;set; NotifyPropChange("Customer"); }
public int Weight { get; set; NotifyPropChange("Weight"); }
public int Data1 { get; set; NotifyPropChange("Data1"); }
public int Data2 { get; set; NotifyPropChange("Data2"); }
public RuntimeData Data3 { get; set; NotifyPropChange("RuntimeData");}
```

Class `RuntimeData` is as follows:

```
public class RuntimeData
{
    public int[] Parameter;

    public RuntimeData()
    {
        Parameter = new int[121];
    }
}
```

I need to display these data via a DataGrid, which is simply:

```
<DataGrid Margin="1,20,1,15.2"/>
```

The problem comes from the fact that "Data3.Parameters" is an array of 121 elements.

I don't know how to correctly bind data so that I'll get a DataGrid with 126 columns ("Program", "Customer", "Weight", "Data1", "Data2" and 121 parameters from "Data3.Parameter").

I think that manually create each of these 126 columns is a wrong way.

Comment: The technology is build around strongly typed dataset, so you will avoid a lot of issues if you make the class with 126 properties. For a reporting module I made a lot more and it performed fine for me.

Comment: Is it truly the only way, cause, if there's 1000 variables or even more, this approach sound, well, bad.